# Again, transitive closure and identity

Tags: isabelle

I have another theorem that I am not being able to prove in Isabelle, involving identity and transitive closure.

It is the following:

```
lemma "r ⊆ Id ⟹ r^* = Id"
```

**Update:** Using apply-style I have the following:

```
lemma "r ⊆ Id ⟹r^* = Id"
  apply (rule equalityI)
  apply (rule subrelI)
  apply (erule rtrancl_induct)
  apply (blast+)
done
```

How can the same be done in Isar?

Comment: Please first tell us what you have already tried. And once more: how would you prove this on paper? Btw: don't post this as an answer then, but rather write comments or update your original post.

Comment: I added your comment to your original question. An answer will follow shortly.

Comment: Again, we apply the canonical way of proving equalities that you mentioned. One side is trivial; the other side involves induction by using the hypothesis. I have tried this in this second stage and I was able to put this reasoning with commands and prove it, but I was not able to formalise the reasoning as an Isar proof. Now I wonder how the Isar proof would be; in Isar I was not able to use my hypothesis 'r ⊆ Id'. The command-mode proof gives:  lemma "r ⊆ Id ⟹r^* = Id"
  apply (rule equalityI)
  apply (rule subrelI)
  apply (erule rtrancl_induct)
  by (blast+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your question is more about transforming apply-style proofs into proper Isar. For the specific example you have this can be done as follows. As you mentioned yourself in

```
lemma "r ⊆ Id ⟹ r^* = Id"
```

there are difficulties to refer to the assumption `r ⊆ Id`. The canonical Isar way of structuring this proof is as follows. We start a proof via

```
proof -
```

where the `-` indicates that *no* initial rule should be used. This just serves the purpose to be able to state assumptions explicitly.

```
  assume *: "r ⊆ Id"
  show "r^* = Id"
```

In addition we give the name `*` to the assumption. Alternatively we could have stated the whole lemma differently as

```
lemma
  assumes *: "r ⊆ Id"
  shows "r^* = Id"
```

which saves one level of nesting. Anyway, having this, as you said, equality of sets is again canonical, namely:

```
proof
  show "r^* ⊆ Id"
  proof (rule subrelI)
    fix x y
    assume "(x, y) ∈ r^*"
    then show "(x, y) ∈ Id"
      using * by (induct) blast+
```

The above line is where we use the assumption (alternatively, we could refer to the assumption literally via `‹r ⊆ Id›` or via the implicit name `assms` that is introduced for the facts following `assumes`). And we finish by:

```
  qed
next
  show "Id ⊆ r^*" by blast
qed
```